# Book recommendations on Gabor filter and Fourier series

Tags: reference-request, fourier-series, gabor, self-study

I'm starting to learn about Gabor filters and Fourier series. I need to make a presentation on Gabor filters in a few months, so I need quality references for the presentation.

Does anyone have any suggestions on introductory books, useful articles or other similar literature which I may use as references for theory on Gabor filters and Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a book that I would recommend as a starting point: [Richard Szeliski: *Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications*](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf)

Comment: Hey, I hope you don't mind, I added the full name of the author and the book in your answer. Firstly, I think it's the least we can do to acknowledge the authors, and secondly, it makes the answer still useful even if the link stops working at some point. Also, it wouldn't hurt to add one or two sentences to your answer elaborating why you would recommend exactly this book for exactly this problem: while links are useful, elaborated answers are almost always more appreciated.

Comment: @penelope: Sorry for being careless.

Comment: Not all of us think about things the same way, it's normal. As somebody working in academia, I think about things like acknowledgment and sharing knowledge all the time. In any case, this is why this is a _community_ :)